# Jsoup will not scrape entire HTML from web page

Tags: java, jsoup

I currently have an instance of a Document object. The Document object uses JSoup's connect method to fetch a Http Request. When I call the .html() method on the instance *doc* and print the result, there seems to be missing tags. When comparing my output to the source code on my browser (FireFox), there seems to be missing elements (More specifically, a youtube video for instance will have a div tag with a class attribute of "html5-video-container").

For reference the source code that I am using is as follows:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsoupTester {

public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ycPr5-27vSI").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/1.0 Mobile/12F69 Safari/600.1.4").get();
        System.out.println(doc.html());

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Keep in mind that you are loading the HTML code, but most likely not execute any javascript code which is embedded in the HTML code.

Comment: Also note that YouTube sends back different HTML based on the User agent. If you access this in Firefox, and have not changed Firefox's user agent, you'll be getting different HTML.

Comment: I've already made sure to change my User-Agent by calling the userAgent method provided by the Connection class. Shouldn't be an issue.